# Optimise permutation code in C to run within time limit

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to solve this challenge:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/permutations-of-strings/problem

The code is supposed to generate permutations of strings in a lexicographical order.

This is the algorithm I am trying to implement (taken from Wikipedia):

```
1. Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
2. Find the largest index l greater than k such that a[k] < a[l].
3. Swap the value of a[k] with that of a[l].
4. Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].
```

My code runs perfectly on all but one test cases, which is terminated due to a timeout. On my machine (locally) the code runs perfectly on that test case too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void swap(char** s1, char** s2) // swaps two strings
{
    char* temp = *s1;
    *s1 = *s2;
    *s2 = temp;
}
int next_permutation(int n, char **s) 
{
    /**
    * Complete this method
    * Return 0 when there is no next permutation and 1 otherwise
    * Modify array s to its next permutation
    */
    int k, i, l;
    k = i = l = 0;

    for(i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) // step 1
        if(strcmp(s[i], s[i + 1]) < 0) {
            k = i;
            break;
        }


    if(i == -1)
        return 0;

    for(i = n - 1; i >= k + 1; i--) // step 2
        if(strcmp(s[k], s[i]) < 0) {
            l = i;
            break;
        }


    swap(&s[k], &s[l]); // step 3

    for(i = n - 1; i > (k + 1 + n - 1) / 2; i--) // step 4
        swap(&s[i], &s[n - 1 - i + k + 1]);

    return 1;
}

int main() // locked code
{
    char **s;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    s = calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        s[i] = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
    }
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s%c", s[i], i == n - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
    } while (next_permutation(n, s));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(s[i]);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the test case on which it times out:

```
8
nrify
tsomld
ubvns
wmgyym
xdyqyfpec
xkpafs
xvd
ysboegsv
```

The expected output is : 
https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/65303/output36.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1591006903&Signature=SL4ZoBvj2Zp84iAlmheZYs1LePs%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

How can I optimise it to run within the time limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimisation was required on step 4.

Instead of

```
for(i = n - 1; i > (k + 1 + n - 1) / 2; i--) // step 4
        swap(&s[i], &s[n - 1 - i + k + 1]);
```

a better alternative would be

```
int inner = k + 1 + n - 1; // step 4
int cond = inner / 2;
for(i = n - 1; i > cond; i--)
    swap(&s[i], &s[inner - i]);
```

Since in this version the condition as well as array index is not calculation expensive in each iteration.